# protobuf-net Serialize a nested list of objects using SerializeWithLengthPrefix

Tags: c#, protobuf-net

I'm currently trying to serialize the following data structure using protobuf-net:

```
[ProtoContract]
public class Recording
{
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public string Name;

    [ProtoMember(2)]
    public List<Channel> Channels;
}

[ProtoContract]
public class Channel
{
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public string ChannelName;

    [ProtoMember(2)]
    public List<float> DataPoints;
}
```

I have a fixed amount of 12 channels, however the amount of datapoints per channel can get very big (up to the Gb range for all channels).
Therefor (and because the data is a continuous stream) I don't want to read and save the structure for one recording at once, but utilise SerializeWithLengthPrefix (and DeserializeItems) to also save it continuously.
My question is, is it even possible to do this with such a nested structure or do I have to flatten it?
I've seen the examples for a list in the first hierarchy level, but none for my specific case.
Also, is there any benefit if I'd write the datapoints as "chunks" of 10, 100, ... (like using List instead of List) over serializing them directly?

Thanks in advance for your help

Tobias

Comment: Can I confirm: do you have a list of separate `Recording` instances? or is this a single `Recording`, and the "list" we're talking about is the `Channels`? It can do both, but I need to know the exact scenario to give you the best advice.

Comment: Every recording should get its own file, so just one recording and the list I want to add data to is the list of datapoints, the list of channels is fixed and the channels are created before the recording starts.

Comment: so the huge list here is the `Channels` one?

Comment: No, the huge ones are the lists of datapoints (I get 1000 of them per second per channel for the 12 channels)

Comment: so what is the item you are appending each time? Sub-objects (such as an individual channel) are typically written in their entirety. Is the intent to write part of channel A with some data-points, B, etc, then more of channel A with some data-points, etc?

Comment: Exactly, I get the datapoints for each channel at the same time, so it will be like: Append x points to A, to B, ... , append next x points to A, B, ...

Comment: The problem is: A & B are (under normal rules) going to be at **very** different points in the file; to *append*, it would basically need to come back in as though it is a *new* channel each time it switched. The consuming code would need to stitch them back together. It depends how happy you are with that. protobuf-net *can be used* to implement a raw streaming API, but the serializer part of it is largely object based... frankly I wonder whether you'd do better to stick to a raw streaming API.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key challenge in what you are trying to do is that it is heavily stream based *internally* to each object. protobuf-net can work in that way, but it is not trivial. There is also an issue that you want to interleave data from a single channel over multiple fragments, which is not idiomatic protobuf layout. So the core *object materializer* code probably doesn't do quite what you want - i.e. treat it as an open stream, not all loaded into memory, for both read and write.

That said: you *could* use the raw reader/writer API to achieve streaming. You should probably compare and contrast to similar code using `BinaryWriter` / `BinaryReader`, but essentially the following works:

```
using ProtoBuf;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
static class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var path = "big.blob";
        WriteFile(path);

        int channelTotal = 0, pointTotal = 0;
        foreach(var channel in ReadChannels(path))
        {
            channelTotal++;
            pointTotal += channel.Points.Count;
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Read: {0} points in {1} channels", pointTotal, channelTotal);
    }
    private static void WriteFile(string path)
    {
        string[] channels = {"up", "down", "top", "bottom", "charm", "strange"};
        var rand = new Random(123456);

        int totalPoints = 0, totalChannels = 0;
        using (var encoder = new DataEncoder(path, "My file"))
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
            {
                var channel = new Channel {
                    Name = channels[rand.Next(channels.Length)]
                };
                int count = rand.Next(1, 50);
                var data = new List<float>(count);
                for (int j = 0; j < count; j++)
                    data.Add((float)rand.NextDouble());
                channel.Points = data;
                encoder.AddChannel(channel);
                totalPoints += count;
                totalChannels++;
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Wrote: {0} points in {1} channels; {2} bytes", totalPoints, totalChannels, new FileInfo(path).Length);
    }
    public class Channel
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public List<float> Points { get; set; }
    }
    public class DataEncoder : IDisposable
    {
        private Stream stream;
        private ProtoWriter writer;
        public DataEncoder(string path, string recordingName)
        {
            stream = File.Create(path);
            writer = new ProtoWriter(stream, null, null);

            if (recordingName != null)
            {
                ProtoWriter.WriteFieldHeader(1, WireType.String, writer);
                ProtoWriter.WriteString(recordingName, writer);
            }
        }
        public void AddChannel(Channel channel)
        {
            ProtoWriter.WriteFieldHeader(2, WireType.StartGroup, writer);
            var channelTok = ProtoWriter.StartSubItem(null, writer);

            if (channel.Name != null)
            {
                ProtoWriter.WriteFieldHeader(1, WireType.String, writer);
                ProtoWriter.WriteString(channel.Name, writer);
            }
            var list = channel.Points;
            if (list != null)
            {

                switch(list.Count)
                {
                    case 0:
                        // nothing to write
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        ProtoWriter.WriteFieldHeader(2, WireType.Fixed32, writer);
                        ProtoWriter.WriteSingle(list[0], writer);
                        break;
                    default:
                        ProtoWriter.WriteFieldHeader(2, WireType.String, writer);
                        var dataToken = ProtoWriter.StartSubItem(null, writer);
                        ProtoWriter.SetPackedField(2, writer);
                        foreach (var val in list)
                        {
                            ProtoWriter.WriteFieldHeader(2, WireType.Fixed32, writer);
                            ProtoWriter.WriteSingle(val, writer);
                        }
                        ProtoWriter.EndSubItem(dataToken, writer);
                        break;
                }
            }
            ProtoWriter.EndSubItem(channelTok, writer);
        }
        public void Dispose()
        {
            using (writer) { if (writer != null) writer.Close(); }
            writer = null;
            using (stream) { if (stream != null) stream.Close(); }
            stream = null;
        }
    }

    private static IEnumerable<Channel> ReadChannels(string path)
    {
        using (var file = File.OpenRead(path))
        using (var reader = new ProtoReader(file, null, null))
        {
            while (reader.ReadFieldHeader() > 0)
            {
                switch (reader.FieldNumber)
                {
                    case 1:
                        Console.WriteLine("Recording name: {0}", reader.ReadString());
                        break;
                    case 2: // each "2" instance represents a different "Channel" or a channel switch
                        var channelToken = ProtoReader.StartSubItem(reader);
                        int floatCount = 0;
                        List<float> list = new List<float>();
                        Channel channel = new Channel { Points = list };
                        while (reader.ReadFieldHeader() > 0)
                        {

                            switch (reader.FieldNumber)
                            {
                                case 1:
                                    channel.Name = reader.ReadString();
                                    break;
                                case 2:
                                    switch (reader.WireType)
                                    {
                                        case WireType.String: // packed array - multiple floats
                                            var dataToken = ProtoReader.StartSubItem(reader);
                                            while (ProtoReader.HasSubValue(WireType.Fixed32, reader))
                                            {
                                                list.Add(reader.ReadSingle());
                                                floatCount++;
                                            }
                                            ProtoReader.EndSubItem(dataToken, reader);
                                            break;
                                        case WireType.Fixed32: // simple float
                                            list.Add(reader.ReadSingle());
                                            floatCount++; // got 1
                                            break;
                                        default:
                                            Console.WriteLine("Unexpected data wire-type: {0}", reader.WireType);
                                            break;
                                    }
                                    break;
                                default:
                                    Console.WriteLine("Unexpected field in channel: {0}/{1}", reader.FieldNumber, reader.WireType);
                                    reader.SkipField();
                                    break;
                            }
                        }
                        ProtoReader.EndSubItem(channelToken, reader);
                        yield return channel;
                        break;
                    default:
                        Console.WriteLine("Unexpected field in recording: {0}/{1}", reader.FieldNumber, reader.WireType);
                        reader.SkipField();
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help :)
I first came up with a similar solution, however I then decided to put the data into chunks so I can make one list of data chunks in the recording class each holding the next X datapoints for every channel.
Then I realized that for the visualization of that data just being able to go through from the beginning won't work very well (and protobuf doesn't support a request like take the next 10 chunks from position 300 on, right?) so I will most likely need another approach.
However again, thanks anyway for your help :)

Comment: @Tobias if you can guarantee that offset 300 is a sane position, there are things you can do - it isn't the normal usage, though

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't express myself clear enough: with "from position 300 on" I mean skip the first 299 chunks and then read the next 10, not from byte 300 on. And for this I could again use the ProtoReader, right?